# Configure security for Spring Boot 2.0 acuator framework

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-boot-actuator

I would like to use Spring Actuator Framework in my Spring Boot 2.0 application. The framework itself works as expected, thus I am able to reach e.g. my `/actuator/health` endpoint. There I´m presented a login dialogue. I´d like to get rid of it and tried the following:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

    return http
               .authorizeExchange()
                   .matchers(EndpointRequest.to("prometheus")).permitAll()
                   .matchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).authenticated()
                   .anyExchange().permitAll()
                   .and()
               .formLogin()
                  .and()
               .httpBasic()
                  .and()
               .build();
  }
```

However, during application startup I get the following error:

> Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain]: Factory method 'securityWebFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: authenticationManager cannot be null

Of course I tried to search for it, but I always only get pages describing different scenarios or security configuration with Spring Boot 1.x framework. Can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, the easiest way to do it should be to have your `SecurityConfiguration` extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and override `configure(WebSecurity web)`, like so:

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**");
    }

    // ...

}
```

Also, I'm not familiar with `@EnableWebFluxSecurity`, but for the above to work, you'd need both the `@Configuration` and the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation.

Now as for the way your configuration is setup, it's not really optimal. To complement the above suggestion, you should configure your security using [HttpSecurity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html) instead of using your current `SecurityWebFilterChain`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestions. 
_To complement the above suggestion, you should configure your security using HttpSecurity instead of using your current SecurityWebFilterChain_ 
Can you tell me, how to do  that? I´ve never configured something for the use of SecurityWebFilterChain

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer from Twin has already received upvotes and the question is old: if you want to secure the Actuator endpoints by using Basic Auth, you also need to provide a suitable AuthenticationManager. The AuthenticationManager authenticates a username+password against some kind of repository.

In the following example the request is authenticated against a user defined in application.yml:

**SecurityConfig**

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

  private final SecurityProperties securityProperties;

  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain actuator(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http
        .authorizeExchange()
        .matchers(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint().excluding("prometheus")).hasRole("ACTUATOR")
        .anyExchange().permitAll()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .authenticationManager(new UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager(
            new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(new User(securityProperties.getUser().getName(),
                "{noop}".concat(securityProperties.getUser().getPassword()),
                securityProperties.getUser().getRoles().stream().map("ROLE_"::concat).map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())))))
        .securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())
        .and()
        .requestCache().disable() // disables websession creation
        .build();
  }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
spring:
  security:
    user:
      name: username
      password: password
      roles: ACTUATOR
```

This is not production ready, you shouldn't place the password in your sourcecode.